# Unnest DataFrame List

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I have a pandas dataframe with a column containing data nested in the following way:

1st Row:
`[('QT', 0, 2, 'PERSON'), ('Billionaire Jack Ma', 102, 121, 'PERSON'), ('$14 million', 131, 142, 'MONEY'), ('U.S.', 204, 208, 'GPE'), ('33', 226, 228, 'MONEY')]`

2nd Row:
`[('My PhD   Mol', 61, 73, 'PERSON'), ('4', 151, 152, 'CARDINAL'), ('100%', 194, 198, 'PERCENT')]`

I need to unnest each group of 4 into 4 separate columns, retaining the original row index as the identifying variable.

Ideal output:

[image]

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the performance, but if I understood well your problem this would work:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'org_id': [idx_val for idx_val in org_df.index for i in range(len(org_df.loc[idx_val, 'target_col']))], 
                     'col_1': [single_tuple[1] for row_value in org_df['target_col'] for single_tuple in row_value], 
                     'col_2': [single_tuple[1] for row_value in org_df['target_col'] for single_tuple in row_value],
                     'col_3': [single_tuple[2] for row_value in org_df['target_col'] for single_tuple in row_value], 
                     'col_4': [single_tuple[3] for row_value in org_df['target_col'] for single_tuple in row_value]})
```

**EDIT**: better performance version, avoids repeating the comprehension:

```
data = {}
# For each index value, repeat n = len(row_list) times
data['org_id'] = [idx_val for idx_val in org_df.index for i in range(len(org_df.loc[idx_val, 'target_col']))]
# Extract each value of each tuple in a specific column
data['col_1'], data['col_2'], data['col_3'], data['col_4'] = zip(*[single_tuple for row_value in org_df['target_col'] for single_tuple in row_value])
result_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```